# Does Mongoose $pop remove the element immediately or only after save?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

From these docs: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types_array_MongooseArray-%24pop

If I were to call  `var popped = doc.array.$pop();`, does Mongoose remove that value immediately from the database document or only after save? If I had several connections that each called $pop(), would they each get the same value until one connection ran the save() command on the doc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `$pop` only affects the local copy of the document until `save` is called.  Only then will be the database document be updated.

So yes, if you had several connections that each called `$pop`, they could each get the same value until `save` is called by one of them.

`$pop` is a pretty awkward API for anything but trivial cases.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to do what I suggested? Just save quickly?

Comment: @DanMandle That's really a separate question, but you'd probably want to use `findAndModify` with the `$pop` operator (not the Mongoose method).